# What's the best way to handle memcache servers that fail?

Tags: memcached

If the server doesn't respond during a set or get operation, will memcache remove the server from the pool automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Your memcache client will decide to remove the server from the pool or not.

If you have consistant hashing turned on, the client will not remove the server from the pool, otherwise the key/value will go to another memcache server.